# NextJS - Protected route not working creating the following error (Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>))

Tags: reactjs, json, firebase-authentication, next.js

Trying to implement protected routes but there is an error that occurs at the AuthUserProvider component. What I'm hoping to do is pass the firebase user information via the routes so I can send the user to the login page if they're not signed in. What is happening is that the user file is returning null even when a sign-in is performed.

Here is the error text:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
> at JSON.parse ()
> at getUserFromCookie (userCookies.js:9)
> at useUser.js:47

I've called the user data here and then sent it through to the children. Or I think I have. Here is the code in the AuthUserProvider file that i've attempted:

```
import { createContext, useContext, Context } from "react";
import useUser from "../firebase/useUser";

const authUserContext = createContext({
    user: null,
});

export function AuthUserProvider({ children }) {
    const auth = useUser();
    return (
        <authUserContext.Provider value={auth}>{children}</authUserContext.Provider>
    );
}
// custom hook to use the authUserContext and access authUser and loading
export const useAuth = () => useContext(authUserContext);
```

Here is the useUser code where I have set up to call the user information via a token:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import initFirebase from "./initFirebase";
import {
    removeUserCookie,
    setUserCookie,
    getUserFromCookie,
} from "./userCookies";
import { mapUserData } from "./mapUserData";

initFirebase();

export default function useUser() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const router = useRouter();

    const logout = async () => {
        return firebase
            .auth()
            .signOut()
            .then(() => {
                // Sign-out successful.
                router.push("/auth");
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.error(e);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // Firebase updates the id token every hour, this
        // makes sure the react state and the cookie are
        // both kept up to date
        const cancelAuthListener = firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                const userData = mapUserData(user);
                setUserCookie(userData);
                setUser(userData);
            } else {
                removeUserCookie();
                setUser();
            }
        });

        const userFromCookie = getUserFromCookie();
        if (!userFromCookie) {
            router.push("/");
            return;
        }
        setUser(userFromCookie);

        return () => {
            cancelAuthListener();
        };
    }, []);

    return { user, logout };
}
```

Here is the getUseFromCookie & setUserCookie code:

```
import cookies from "js-cookie";

export const getUserFromCookie = () => {
    const cookie = cookies.get("auth");
    if (!cookie) {
        return;
    }

    return JSON.parse(cookie);
};

export const setUserCookie = (user) => {
    cookies.set("auth", user, {
        expires: 1 / 24,
    });
};

export const removeUserCookie = () => cookies.remove("auth");
```

Comment: That usually means you're trying to parse `'[object Object]'` as if it was JSON.

Comment: What does the `getUserFromCookie` function look like? Are you passing the right value to `JSON.parse` inside it?

Comment: @juliomalves, i've added the function. I do parse the json in the function. Maybe that's where the problem is?

Comment: Is `cookies.get("auth")` returning the expected value? Also, are you certain you're storing the right value when calling `setUserCookie` after successful authentication? It does look like the value stored in the cookie isn't correct.

Comment: @juliomalves Looks like it's Cookies.set('name', 'value', { path: '' }) is how the js-cookie documentation says. I wonder if the issue is how i'm using createContext

Comment: Removed the JSON.parse(cookie) and it worked.... changed it to just the cookie. @jonrsharpe 

Not sure why it works now though